# ExtJs - Ext.createAlias in app.js

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

If I run:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true}); //Why is this here?

Ext.application({
    name: 'APP',
    appFolder: 'app',
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    /*uses: [
        'APP.view.Viewport'
    ],*/
    controllers: [
        'Controller'
    ]
});
```

I get the following error:

```
[06:52:09.773] Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an 
instance of unrecognized alias: writer.json
```

However, if I uncomment out the 'uses', it works fine. If I switch 'uses' for 'requires' I get the same error as above.

I feel like I shouldn't need that 'uses' but I do. I'm really confused about why I need it. I don't like having magic code.

EDIT: I have views: ['Viewport'] in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is not related to the code you posted. Ext is trying to create json writer (because it is configured elsewhere, most likely a model or a store) but the class `Ext.data.writer.Json` is not declared in `requires:[]` of that file.

Check all your files to find something like:

```
 writer:{
     type:'json'
 }
```

and require the writer in that class.

Comment: That was it. I couldn't tell what file(s) needed it, but I started at the root and made my way down. It turns out a file that extended GeoExt needed it.